# How can I get execution context in a signal handler?

Tags: c, linux, signals, x86-64

I am getting `illegal operand` error when I run a program. The program where the crash happens is written in assembly and linked as an object file, so I'm not sure how to use `gdb` with it. I noticed the fault by trapping the `SIGILL` signal.I want to get the address of the offending instruction. One method that comes to my mind is to get the last execution context in the signal handler and note down the value of `rip` register from it. I know that context is passed to signal handlers, but don't know how.

Comment: Surely running your program under a debugger (e.g, GDB) is a simpler solution than having it try to trap its own exceptions?

Comment: I link my assembly part of the program as an object file. And it is there that the crash is happening. How can I use gdb there?

Comment: Run the application under GDB (`gdb myapp`; `run`). When it throws an exception, it will break into the debugger, and you can use commands like `info reg` to view the execution state of the program when it crashed.

Comment: it is possible to do what you want with a signal handler (see my answer), but as others have noted I think it would probably be easier to do get this information in gdb directly without having to write a signal handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do want to follow the signal handler route it is not hard to get the address of the instruction that causes the signal handler to run.  When you create your signal handler set the `SA_SIGINFO` bit in the flags setting.  Then when you write your handler it will have access to a `siginfo_t` structure that includes the field `si_addr` which is the address of the memory location that triggered the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> written in assembly and linked as an object file, so I'm not sure how to use gdb with it

GDB is perfectly fine for debugging assembly code. You'll want `info registers`, `x/i $pc`.

> One method that comes to my mind is to get the last execution context in the signal handler and note down the value of rip register from it.

That's fine (see Gabriel's answer on how to get the context).

Please note that this will *not* give you any additional info compared to what you get inside GDB at crash point. If you didn't know how to use GDB in the first place, then I don't see what you'll gain by getting the context in a signal handler.